# Errors untar Hbase tar.gz file (1.2.6)

Tags: hbase

I'm trying installing `hbase-1.2.6-bin.tar.gz` in `/usr/local`, but I keep having the following error in the command line: (I'm using last mac OS version)

```
x hbase-1.2.6/LICENSE.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
x hbase-1.2.6/NOTICE.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
x hbase-1.2.6/LEGAL: Can't unlink already-existing object
x hbase-1.2.6/docs/: Can't update time for hbase-1.2.6/docs
x hbase-1.2.6/docs/devapidocs/: Can't update time for hbase-1.2.6/docs/devapidocs
x hbase-1.2.6/docs/devapidocs/com/: Can't update time for hbase-1.2.6/docs/devapidocs/com
x hbase-1.2.6/docs/devapidocs/com/google/: Can't update time for hbase-1.2.6/docs/devapidocs/com/google
x hbase-1.2.6/docs/devapidocs/com/google/protobuf/: Can't update time for hbase-1.2.6/docs/devapidocs/com/google/protobuf
x hbase-1.2.6/docs/devapidocs/com/google/protobuf/class-use/: Can't update time for hbase-1.2.6/docs/devapidocs/com/google/protobuf/class-use
x hbase-1.2.6/docs/devapidocs/resources/: Can't update time for hbase-1.2.6/docs/devapidocs/resources
x hbase-1.2.6/docs/devapidocs/org/: Can't update time for hbase-1.2.6/docs/devapidocs/org
x hbase-1.2.6/docs/devapidocs/org/apache/: Can't update time for hbase-1.2.6/docs/devapidocs/org/apache
x hbase-1.2.6/docs/devapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/: Can't update time for hbase-1.2.6/docs/devapidocs/org/apache/hadoop
x hbase-1.2.6/docs/devapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/: Can't update time for hbase-1.2.6/docs/devapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase
```

And so on, the error log is larger...

Could you please help me solving this issue ?

Thank you
Habib

Comment: What was the command that you executed? Did you use `sudo`? Did you check if the package is not corrupted?

Comment: Hello, the package was ok, I didn't have the right brew version, so I tried with "brew update". This command lead me to download xcode, because the error: